# what is the code for power_interaction_r2?

Tags: r, path

What is the code for power_interaction_r2 in the library `InteractionPoweR`, or how do I find this out?

I have tried finding the file path via `file.choose()` but was confused as to what file to select.

I would appreciate either the raw code or how to find this out in the future or both if possible

Comment: Already tried typing  `InteractionPoweR::power_interaction_r2` in console? Or find it on github: https://github.com/dbaranger/InteractionPoweR/blob/HEAD/R/power_interaction_r2.R

Comment: I am relatively new at coding and R so thanks for this. It seems to have given a lot of code , a separate bytecode and then a environment line. How much do I need? Thanks for the GitHub suggestion as it was the same as the code. Perfect

Comment: Everything except bytecode and environment.